# Xamarin.Forms как подстроке текста добавить интерактив

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xaml, xamarin

Есть некий большой текст, в разных его местах нужно выделить несколько подстрок (слов): форматировать (например выделить другим цветом) и повесить взаимодействие (например TapGestureRecognizer). По поведению должно напоминать HTML ссылки в тексте на сайте - выделенные слова в тексте, при тапе на которые открывался бы браузер и переходил на соответствующий URL.

Если положить сам текст в Label, и каждую подстроку так же кидать в Label, то получится разрыв текста, а текст должен сохранять целостность и пунктуацию, никаких лишних пробелов и разрывов.

Погуглив, я нашел для Label такую штуку как FormattedString и Span, но Во-первых, Span это sealed и его никак не расширить, в отличие от Label, которому прям можно и добавить аттрибут Href, а Во-вторых в Span не за что зацепиться чтобы как-то идентифицировать эту подстроку и обращаться именно к ней из кода.

Подскажите куда копать, может я зря заморачиваюсь с Label и для этих целей есть более удобные контейнеры?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте вот так

```
 <Button StyleClass = "Link"/>
```

Если не подойдет, можно вот так

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = "http://www.google.com/";

var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => 
{
    Device.OpenUri( new Uri((Label)s).Text);
};
label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```